# Accessing multiple instances of classes in an efficient way in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop

I have a class `users` that has many functions, such as `user.CompletedProfile()` and `user.GetUpdateHistory()`. When a single user is logged in, that class is instantiated and it is fast enough to use as a single instance.

How can I access the class in a massive way that isn't too taxing on my database queries? For example, if I have 10,000 users and I want to generate a table of information on all of them, is there a better way to access all of those users than instantiating 10,000 new objects (and all of the database queries that go with each)?

Or, is it simpler to write a second class `users` that performs these types of lookups? This solution doesn't seem right to me, since things might change in the `user` class and I would have to make sure they also change in the `users` class.

Comment: 'user' should likely extend 'users' then.

Comment: Did u have Relational database? Or just some Tables? Or only one Table?

Comment: How can I access the class in a massive way that isn't too taxing on my database queries? - if you want to use mysl_query fetch_object, it is always slow! If not see:design pattern FLIGHTWIGHT

Comment: I'm using MySQL with PDO (not mysql_) and the `user` class is accessing many tables, such as `users`, `user_update_history`, `user_experience`, etc.

Comment: maybe for 'make sure they also change in the users class' use design pattern observer! to notify aboud updates. How taxing it all is lays in the way u implement it ;)

Comment: and if 'if I have 10,000 users and I want to generate a table of information on all of them' maby thing about using: ajax tables & restfull api - that is better than to try 10000 rows at once. but too less information about: processflow and implementation, dude